# jquery problems with hover, click and if statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I have a function that disables the link action on first click when hovering, then allows the link action on the second click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function () {

        $("#menu ul > li").hover(function () {
            i = 1;
            if ($('div', this).children().size() > 0) {
                $('.drop', this).addClass("locked");
            }

            $('.locked').click(function () {
                if (i < 2) {
                    i++;
                    console.log("if 1 i = ", i);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    i = 1;
                    console.log("if 2 i = ", i);

                }
            });

            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
            $('div', this).stop(true, true).delay(300).slideDown(200);
        }, function () {
            $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function () {}, this), 100));
            $('div', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
            $('.drop', this).removeClass("locked");
            i = 1;

        });

    });
</script>
```

On the first hover the function works fine, but if I let the function run without click move the mouse out of the hover element then return and "drop" the menu again the if's in the .click stop working. In the console it appears as if the if clauses are just being looped straight through.
Any Ideas why?

Comment: Could you post a jsFiddle link?

Comment: here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VJZW8/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my own solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function() {
    var  drop_i = 1;

               $("#menu ul > li").hover(function () {

               if($('div', this).children().size() > 0){
               $('.drop', this).addClass( "locked" );                                      
               }                   
               clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
                  $('div', this).stop(true, true).delay(300).slideDown(200);
                },                     
                function () {
               $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
              }, this), 100));
               $('div', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
               $('.drop', this).removeClass( "locked" );


              });

                $('.drop').click(function(){
                console.log("clicked");
                if (drop_i < 2 && $('.drop').hasClass('locked')) {                   
                 drop_i++;
                 console.log("if 1 i = ", drop_i);
                 return false;
                }
                else { 
                 drop_i = 1;
                 console.log("if 2 i = ", drop_i);
                //return true;
                }                   
              });                    


           });



         </script>
```

Works OK now.

Comment: I also added: drop_i = 1; under: $('.drop', this).removeClass( "locked" );

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var  i = 1;//yuo may want to re-name this since it is now global
    $('document').ready(function () {

        $("#menu ul > li").hover(function () {
            i = 1;
            if ($('div', this).children().size() > 0) {
                $('.drop', this).addClass("locked");
            }



            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
            $('div', this).stop(true, true).delay(300).slideDown(200);
        }, function () {
            $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function () {}, this), 100));
            $('div', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
            $('.drop', this).removeClass("locked");
            i = 1;

        });

         $('.locked').click(function () {
                if (i < 2) {
                    i++;
                    console.log("if 1 i = ", i);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    i = 1;
                    console.log("if 2 i = ", i);

                }
            });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry this just allows the link to be clicked first time. I need the link to fire on the second click only. see js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VJZW8/2/